# nested routing projection via router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular-router

I am using nested routing like this what i am expecting it should show test2Component on upper level of router-outlet which is in app.component.html if the router-outlet is not exist in testComponent.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [{ path: "test2", component: Test2Component }]
  }
];
```

[Playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cvnueu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

Comment: You can try using lazy loading with your routes.  For example you can put the first router-outlet inside of  'app.component.html'

Comment: router-outlet is already in app.component.html my question with above routing test2Component should projected into app.component.html but which is not in this case why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lazy loading with your routes but it would require you to make more modules.  For example you can put the first router-outlet inside of your app component:

'app.component.html'

```
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

Create a new module, router & component with angular/cli similar to the way you create components:

```
ng g c test
ng g c test/Test2
ng g m test/TestModule
ng g m test/TestRouter --routing
```

Note: make sure the TestModule is imported into the base app module and that the Test & Test2 component is imported into the TestModule.

then in your base app router file add the following:

'app-routing.module.ts'

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule)
  }];
```

Then go to the new module and router you created and add the following:

'test-router.module.ts'

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'test2', component: Test2Component }
    ]
  }];
```

finally add the router-outlet to the parent TestComponent

'test.component.html'

```
<h2>Test component<h2>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

If you would like to look at an example you can look at how I use lazy loading in one of my projects.

app base router example: https://github.com/shahidfoy/chatter/blob/master/chatter/chat-app/src/app/app-routing.module.ts

app child router example: https://github.com/shahidfoy/chatter/blob/master/chatter/chat-app/src/app/streams/streams-routing.module.ts